# How to remove directory access in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and I've created a subdomain

123.xyz.com and the 123 subdomain is connected to the 123 directory but I want to access that directory using only this URL = 123.xyz.com

But that directory is also accessible from xyz.com/123 so, I want to remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have FTP access, you will find the `.htaccess` file in the root folder of your wordpress installation. Maybe this file is hidden, so you will have to find the option in your FTP software to "show hidden files".

Inside of the `.htaccess` file you have to add the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /123 https://123.example.com
```

So there will be a 301 redirect from the first URL in the line to the second. If you visit the example.com/123 you will be redirected to 123.example.com

---

Another way is using a very popular wordpress plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

---

Another way would be to add a function inside of the `functions.php` file of your theme:

```
function mycustom_redirect() {
  global $post;

    if( is_page('123') ) { // the name of your page is 123

        wp_redirect( 'https://123.example.com' );

        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mycustom_redirect' );
```